# How to return Error Message from assertion in Kotlin

Tags: assert, kotlin

I am getting comfortable in Kotlin after switching from Java and could not find out how to use Kotlin's [assert](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/assert.html) function in conjunction with an error message.

Sounds simple, I just need something similar to Java's

```
assert count > 5 : "value too small"
```

I tried

```
assert(count > 5, "value too small")
```

However, the second argument needs to be `() -> Any`. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`assert`'s message parameter is not a String, but a function returning a String. This is so because otherwise, since `assert` is a normal Kotlin function, its arguments would be evaluated every time which would lead to unnecessary overhead (and sometimes change in semantics) of calculating the message string in case that string is a complex expression.

To pass a function argument, use the [lambda syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions). The last argument which is a lambda may be left out of the parentheses:

```
assert(count > 5) { "value too small" }
```

Comment: This does not work at all for me, with the latest Kotlin version. The assertion fails with no trace of the message.

Comment: This doesn't work for the latest version of Kotlin. No message when failing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6):

I got it by myself, I need to declare a lambda function without parameters, which looks like this in Kotlin:

```
assert(count > 5, {"value too small"})
assert(count > 5, { -> "value too small"})
```

Sorry for bothering you! I leave the question, maybe some other beginner will find it useful.

Comment: Parentheses and arrow is reduntant.